# PowerShell Get-ChildItem from variable that only matches beginning

Tags: powershell, scripting

Please bear with me as I know this is probably simple. I'm still learning scripting and PS in particular. What I am attempting to do is delete a bunch of files that begin with 5 numbers. The numbers are formatted as YYDDD to equal 2-digit year and 3-digit julian date.

Each week I have to delete these files from the `previous week`. I ask the user to enter the beginning date, for example, today would be 18303.

It should then delete all files in folder BI and NI beginning with 18303, then move on to 18304, 18305, etc. Right now it appears to working but during testing I am seeing random files that don't appear to match the input being deleted. I have tried to create files where the number to be entered shows up somewhere in the name, just to be sure it's not looking everywhere for the numbers. Just hoping someone can look over the code and see if anything stands out that could be an issue. Or perhaps a better way to achieve what I am trying to do. Thanks!

```
$path0 = 'F:\CompletedTokens\BI'
$path1 = 'F:\CompletedTokens\NI'

$date = Read-Host 'Enter Julian Date as YYDDD'
$dval = $date -as [Int]

for ($i = 0; $i -le 4; $i++) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path0,$path1 -Filter "$dval*" |
        % { Write-Host 'Deleting' $_.FullName; Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse }
    $dval++
}

Pause
```

Comment: One of the first things you want to know about is using `-WhatIf` on cmdlets like `Remove-Item`.

Comment: @lit I know. It's one of the things I keep forgetting about. Unfortunately the rogue file that was deleted during a test is gone and I'm now not sure why it was grouped with the others.

Comment: Sorry I can't follow. Today is DayOfYear 18303, then the **last** week began on  18294 or 18295 depending on your definition of 1st day of week (sun/mon). So why bother with user input?